# Is there a way to check and load missing data to SQL?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, list, pyodbc

I am trying to figure out a way to check data I am loading into a SQL table from a dataframe so I can load missing data and avoid loading duplicate data.

Here is a really rough idea.

```
sql_data = []
data = [(2020-01-01, Monday, 20, 0.1), (2020-01-02, Tuesday, 12, 0.4), (2020-01-01, Wednesday, 26, 0.3)]
          
        
cursor.execute('''Select * FROM Table ''')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
   sql_data.append(row)
    
if data in sql_data:
   pass
else:
   query = '''INSERT INTO Table (Time, Day, Number, Decimal)
                                 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'''
   cursor.execute(query, data)
   conn.commit()
```

Comment: You can set a unique key constraint on the table, which will reject any duplicated data, that might be (attempting to be) loaded.  Additionally, you can try the `DataFrame.to_sql()` function to load the data directly from the DataFrame.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do an "upsert". A web search for that term should give you some ideas.

Comment: @GordThompson - It seems to me (and possibly misunderstanding the question) that OP wants to fill in gaps, rather than updating current records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider rarely used `EXCEPT` clause (part of `UNION` and `INTERSECT` set operator family) since SQL Server supports scalar values in `SELECT` without a `FROM` data source:

```py
query = '''INSERT INTO Table (Time, Day, Number, Decimal)
           SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?
           EXCEPT
           SELECT Time, Day, Number, Decimal
           FROM Table
        '''
cursor.executemany(query, data)
conn.commit()
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/VHKB30232)</kbd>

Comment: I tried this but it returned this                                                                    `cursor.execute(query, list)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXCEPT'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")`

Comment: Since `data` is a list of tuples, use `executemany`. And actually your date fields should be quoted otherwise each is assumed to be mathematical expression of subtraction.